# How to mass search and replace values in a text file with value*2

Tags: search, replace, numbers

I have alot of text files with;

```
Value 800
Amount 50
```

or

```
Value 600
Amount 40
```

I want to double all the numbers

```
Value 1600
Amount 100
```

or

```
Value 1200
Amount 80
```

Is there some very basic program that can search for "value" & "amount" read the integer after and replace with the same value*2

or some way to do this with notepad++, autoIt or some other simple program/tool?

Comment: In what language it is ???

Answer (score 0):

You should at least have a go first, then ask the question ;)

Please backup your files first, then try this autoit script:

```
#include <File.au3>

$textFiles = _FileListToArray(@ScriptDir, "*.txt", 1)

for $fileIndex = 1 to $textFiles[0]
$textFile = $textFiles[$fileIndex]

    ConsoleWrite($textFile & @CRLF)

    Local $lines
    _FileReadToArray($textFile, $lines)

    $output = FileOpen($textFile, 2)

    For $i = 1 To $lines[0]
        $line = $lines[$i]
        $tokens = StringSplit($line, " ")

        If $tokens[0] = 2 Then
            $newLine = $tokens[1] & " " & $tokens[2] * 2
            FileWrite($output, $newLine & @CRLF)
        EndIf
    Next

    FileClose($output)
Next
```